# SQL error or missing database (near ".": syntax error) error in java when trying to update data from sqlite databse

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

i keep getting this error in java. I did look at similar questions but they didnt help. Can someone solve it? thanks

```
UPDATE SearchedWords 
SET SearchedWords.NrOfSearches=SearchedWords.NrOfSearches+1 
FROM SearchedWords
INNER JOIN Dictionary ON SearchedWords.WordID=Dictionary.ID 
WHERE Dictionary.Word=? AND SearchedWords.UserID=?;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't support `JOIN` in `UPDATE`.  Here is one work-around:

```
UPDATE SearchedWords 
    SET NrOfSearches = NrOfSearches + 1 
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Dictionary d
                  WHERE d.ID = SearchedWords.WordID AND
                        d.Word = ?
                 ) AND
          UserID = ?;
```

Comment: thanks, but i am getting the following error "Query does not return results", i dont know if its from the query but from the data i used it on

Comment: it actually works, turns out i had to use prepStatement.execute(); instead of prepStatement.executeQuery();, sqlite truly is garbage, thanks for the help